# Get records from Sql only for require condition in EntityFramewotk in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ienumerable

I am very new in Entity Framework.
For now, I have one model class:

**Model :**

```
public class Search_Model
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string Age {get; set;}

    public string Religion { get; set; }

    public string Mothertongue { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Search_Model> Searcg_Ie { get; set; }
}
```

In my View when user fill the form and all filled values comes to above model & then it will redirect to following action:

**Action :**

```
public ActionResult PublicSearch(Search_Model mdl)
    {
        Search_Model srch = new Search_Model();
        srch.Searcg_Ie = new List<Search_Model> { mdl};
        var rtc = srch.Searcg_Ie.Select(z=>z).Where(s=>s!=null).ToList();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

So my question is, from the above model *Age, Religion, Mothertoungue* fields may be null at runtime. I want a record from database table only for not null values. 
Suppose only *Gender & Age* have the data. So in entity framework we can write this:

```
return(from x in dbcontext.table1
        where x.age=Age,
        where x.gender = Gender
        select new model{
         model properties here..
        }).ToList();
```

That's fine. But how would I do this at runtime when we don't know which property will be null, and how do I write the code for the get records from the SQL database?

**I dont want to find records using null model properties**

Comment: You can use reflection to get the properties on your model, check if they are null or not.  From there, you can build your where clause to exclude null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain as many *Where* clauses as you want and they will be translated into *ands*. So you get *reference to query* and filter it if your condition is met. For example, in your situation it is like this:

```
var query = dbcontext.table1;

if(age != null)
    query = query.Where(m => m.Age == age);

if(gender != null)
    query = query.Where(m => m.Gender == gender);

return  query.Select(m => new model
            {
                model properties here..
            }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return
(from x in dbcontext.table1
    where Age == null || x.age==Age
     && Gender == null || x.gender == Gender
    select new model{
     model properties here..
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: you are right , but if `age==null` then it will find records where age is null, i want actually if age is null then dont find using age property, find using another properties which are not null..

Comment: if your search filter (Age == null ) then x.age==Age will not exist in final query.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking whether your properties equal a value. Either one can match but if one doesn't, the value shouldn't be null.

```
return (from x in dbcontext.table1
where (x.age == Age || x.gender == Gender) && (x.age != null && x.gender != null)
select new {/* properties */}).ToList();
```

Comment: I dont want  to find records using null model properties.find records using not null. model properties only .

Answer (score 0):

You can get expected result by this query

```
var filteredData = dbContext.table1.Where(x =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gender) ? x.Gender == gender : true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(age) ? x.Age == age : true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty        (religion) ? x.Religion == religion : true).ToList();
```

Comment: @ Rahul Chaudhari please try this and it would resolve your problem definitely.

Comment: @ Rahul Chaudhari you can add more properties with && operator like in his query.